# AccessViolation - Attempted to read or write protected memory for a SELECT in Cassandra from C# program

Tags: c#, solr, cassandra

I have a C# program that reads rows from one Cassandra column family. For each row, it has to match some other rows from another Cassandra column family, and in the end update a map collection in the first column family.
Both Cassandra column families are in Solr.
The program crashes throwing the error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

With StackTrace:

```
at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.IColumnsInfo.GetColumnInfo(IntPtr& pcColumns, IntPtr& prgInfo, IntPtr& ppStringsBuffer)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.BuildSchemaTableInfo(Object handle, Boolean filterITypeInfo, Boolean filterChapters)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.BuildMetaInfo()
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Casample.MainApp.selectIndexLinesMain(OleDbConnection conn, ModelInd modelGel) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Intellisoft\CASO\Samples\C#\02_SimpleQuery.cs:line 118
   at Casample.MainApp.Main(String[] args) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Intellisoft\CASO\Samples\C#\MainApp.cs:line 45
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The exception is thrown when I execute this part f the code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id,id2 FROM table2 WHERE  solr_query='{\"q\":\"firstname:\\\"" + model.firstname + "\\\" AND lastname = \\\"" + model.lastname+ "\\\" AND firstname2= \\\"" + model.firstname2 + "\\\" AND lastname2 = \\\"" + model.lastname2 + "\\\" AND -id2:" + model.id2 + "\"}';";

Console.Write(cmd.CommandText);
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The error is thrown at ExecuteReader();

If I execute this program for two column families that are not in Solr, it will work without throwing the exception.

Comment: Have you tried using the core driver instead of the ADO.NET component? ie: `session.Execute(query)`

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my reply! I did try that too, and I get the same error. Also, as an update, when I run the select and rows are returned, I do not receive the error. The only time the error is thrown is when the select does not find any rows.